# Boot from USB without use of SD card at all?

Tags: usb

I have a raspberry pi whose SD card slot is broken so I cannot change the boot options at all like YouTube tutorials say, is there a way to boot my device from a USB without the use of an SD card?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pi3B+ is pre-configured for USB boot. The Pi3B needs one-time configuration. All other models need an SD card at all times.

So if you have a Pi3B+ the answer is yes. Just follow the 'older' tutorials minus the one-time configuration bit.

Comment: I am not sure which one I have, how can I tell

Comment: It's the only one with the metal capped processor and wifi chips. It also says `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+`on the PCB near the GPIO

Comment: Try to have a look inside the card slot to see if pins are bent. Apparently that has happened to users before

Comment: If you can get hold of a soldering iron (the right way, mind), you wouldn't be the first: https://daniel.molkentin.net/2013/03/14/replacing-the-sd-card-reader-on-a-raspberry-pi-for-2-50-euros/

Comment: I am not seeing any pin bendage what does happen though when I put the SD card in is that it just pops out

Comment: If you have a Pi3B you could just hold the card in the slot for the one-time configuration. If it's an older model then you can put a card with just `bootcode.bin` in the slot and put some tape or so over the top to keep it in place. Both boot and root can still be on USB.

Comment: I have already tried the tape method and it just seems to break the tape

Comment: Another suggestion I have seen is to put some tape on the card itself to increase the friction.

Comment: Just found out what model it is: Pi 2 Model B just use the tape method for that?

Comment: Yes, if you can make the card stick you should be OK. You could use the card i the  'classical' way or use 'bootcode.bin on SD card with full system on USB device' method (I would use the bootcode.bin method)

Comment: [Raspberry Pi Documentation - How to boot from a USB mass storage device](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md)